# Stretching backgrond beyond parents width html css

Tags: html, css, background

I want to stretch background color (or an image) so it would look like the bottom example in

[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWUtj/1/)

Same code but here: 
Example1:

```
<div class="fixed_width">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="menu">
      Here be some menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      Here be some content<br/>
      ANd even more
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2

```
<div class="fixed_width">
  <div class="header">Another<br/>Header</div>
  <div class="menu2">
      Here be some menu
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      Here be some content<br/>
      ANd even more
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background: lightgray}
.fixed_width {width: 500px; border: solid thin black; 
  margin: 20px auto; background: white;}
.menu {background: blue; color: white; padding: 20px; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;}
.content {background: white; border: solid thin gray; 
  margin: 5px;}

.menu2 {width: 500px; background: blue; color: white; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;padding: 20px 2000px 20px 2000px; 
  margin-left: -2000px;}
```

Bottom example is something I came up with but the problem is browser wants to scroll to those 2000px on the right.

The structure of the page is similar to the code in jsfiddle and as you can see there is no telling where exactly the top of menu will be - above it there will be a header which can have variable height (so I can not use a nice pre generated whole page background image).

I can not disable scroll because on smaller screens ppl wont be able to scroll. Please help me fix that (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your menu in a wrapping element, give the latter a width of 100% (assuming it is the top most element), and center the menu:

HTML:

```
  <body>
     <div id="menu_wrapper">
        <ul id="menu">
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
         <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
  #menu_wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  }
  #menu 
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as illustrated, Menu is not a top element and its already inside the 'fixed_width' element.

Comment: can't you wrap the #fixed_width div itself? i.e. create different wrappers for each background: a header wrapper, content wrapper, etc..

Comment: if there is no other way to do it then I guess I will have to do just that, but I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: Yes I guess changing the structure is not that big of a deal. Thanks.